# Question about compactness of the zero set of an analytic function of several variables

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> **Hartogs's Theorem** Let $f$ be a  holomorphic function on a set $G \setminus K$, where $G$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ ($n \ge
>  2$) and $K$ is a compact subset of $G$. If the complement $G\setminus
>  K$ is connected, then $f$ can be extended to a unique to a unique
>   holomorphic function on $G$.

This theorem can be used to show the following result about the zeros of analytic functions of several variables.

> Suppose that $f$ is an analytic function on some open set $U$ and that
>   $f$ is not identically zero on $U \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ with $n \ge 2$.
>   Then, the set of zeros of $f$ (i.e. $\Lambda(f)=\{ z: f(z)=0\}$) is not compact.

Since  $\Lambda(f)$ is not compact we can have the following three possibilities:

1. $\Lambda(f)$ is closed but is not bound
2. $\Lambda(f)$ is not closed but  bounded
3. $\Lambda(f)$ is not closed and not bounded

**My question is the following:** 
Can we come up with examples of $f$ for each of the three cases?

Here is an example of the function that satisfies the first case.  Let  $f_1(z_1,z_2)=z_1 \cdot z_2$ then
\begin{align}
\Lambda(f_1)= \{  (z_1,z_2) : z_1=0 \} \cup \{  (z_1,z_2) : z_2=0 \}. 
\end{align}
where  $\Lambda(f_1)$ is closed but not bounded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cases 2 and 3 cannot exist by continuity. Since $f\colon U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic, it is continuous. Hence $\{0\}$ being a closed subset implies that $f^{-1}(0) = \Lambda(f)$ is closed in $U$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. So a more accurate statement about the set of zeros is that it is closed and unbounded, right?

Comment: Closed and unbounded in $U$.

Comment: Can you remind me what unbounded in $U$ means? There exists no ball $B$ that contains $\Lambda(f)$ such that   $B \subset U$?

Comment: It means that the set $\Lambda(f)$ is not contained in any compact subset of $U$. I want to emphasise that because  $U$ may be bounded in $\mathbb{C}^n$. For example, let $U = B(0,1)$ the unitary ball centered at the origin. Then being unbounded in $U$ means that the closure of $\Lambda(f)$ needs to meet the boundary of $U$. However $\Lambda(f)$ is bounded as a subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: Thanks. You very much anticipated what I wanted to ask.

Comment: On another note, do you have a good reference that studies question about zeros of analytic functions of many variables?

Comment: I'd recommend "From holomorphic functions to complex manifolds" by Fritzsche and Grauert. It is an introductory book but worth to be read.